# TypeError: callSite.getFileName is not a function at callSiteLocation (/node_modules/depd/index.js:252:23) on npm start

Tags: node.js, express, npm, babeljs, body-parser

When I am doing npm install in the project that I clone from github & then npm start I am getting error:

```
/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/test-project/node_modules/depd/index.js:252
  var file = callSite.getFileName() || '<anonymous>'
                      ^

TypeError: callSite.getFileName is not a function
    at callSiteLocation (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/test-project/node_modules/depd/index.js:252:23)
    at depd (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/test-project/node_modules/depd/index.js:111:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/test-project/node_modules/body-parser/index.js:14:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/test-project/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:136:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/test-project/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:141:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
```

This 'depd' library is throwing error from all the occurrences as it is a dependancy in various npm packages like body-parser & express. So it is throwing error from within all of them.

However my existing setup from same github repo where I am not doing npm install from scratch seem to be working fine.
I have tried doing npm install with different nodeJs versions 6.9.5, 10.x.x, 11.x.x, 12.x.x
Also I am using Babel v7.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Are you able to edit your answer and provide your `package.json` contents so we can see the dependencies you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Node.js to the latest LTS. I was on 12.x and had this error, so upgrading to 16.x fixed it.